# Спецификация ПО от разработчика

Tags: проектирование, документация, спецификация

Дали задание: подготовить спецификацию ПО от разработчика. Как мне вкратце рассказали, это описание программы с точки зрения программиста, например, какой язык, функционал...

Если кто-то с подобным сталкивался - напишите пару таких пунктов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, спецификация ПО - это SRS. Содержит в себе введение (цели продукта, аудитория и т.д.), набор и описание вариантов использования (usecase) и набор требований (функциональных и нефункциональных).

В вашем случае совершенно логично скачать SRS для какого-нибудь продукта (уверен, найдется) и сделать по образу и подобию.

Comment: Мне не нужно описывать продукт со всех сторон, SRS - не то, что мне надо

Comment: Не бывает спецификаций "от разработчика", "от дизайнера" и т.д.